# How to avoid laravel controller conflicts

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

My laravel route file has two different controllers with same name but in different folder.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Deals;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Deals;
 
Route::get('/deals', [Deals::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/admin/deals', [Deals::class, 'show']);
```

Is there a way possible to rewrite the code and avoid conflict?

What I am expecting

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Deals as Deals;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Deals as AdminDeals;
 
Route::get('/deals', [Deals::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/admin/deals', [AdminDeals::class, 'show']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the way you wrote above will work, but you need to either change the alias or remove it, so that it turns out like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Deals;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Deals as AdminDeals;

Route::get('/deals', [Deals::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/admin/deals', [AdminDeals::class, 'show']);
```

Or you can always use an absolute path to avoid name conflict:

```
Route::get('/deals', [\App\Http\Controllers\Deals::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/admin/deals', [\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Deals::class, 'show']);
```